# mySQL query -- multiple possible specific values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently querying our database using a rather lengthy statement, given how little it does.

```
fieldname like 'expected_result_up' AND `result_text` not like 'obsolete' and
AK47_testsection_id like 436 and ( `resultsfields_value` like 240 or
`resultsfields_value` like 846 or `resultsfields_value` like 1000 )
```

I'm trying to get a value from "resultsfields_value" such that it can be either 240, 846, or 1000. The current query works, it returns every one of the values. But it only works in a manual query through the heidiSQL interface.

When I run the same query with different syntax through php I only get the last "or" (1000) returned. The php DB query is:

```
"SELECT point_id FROM v_ak47_test_point WHERE ak47_testsection_id= $secID
and result_text != 'obsolete' and fieldname like 'expected_result_up' and 
(resultsfields_value = 240 or resultsfields_value = 846 or resultsfields_value =
1000)"
```

Is there a more elegant way to specify multiple unique possibilities?

Comment: Those parentheses around the "OR'ed" fields definitely mean something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an IN clause:

```
SELECT point_id 
FROM v_ak47_test_point 
WHERE ak47_testsection_id= $secID
AND result_text != 'obsolete'
AND fieldname = 'expected_result_up'
AND resultsfields_value IN (240, 846, 1000)
```

Comment: certainly works on hedisql, checking it in my php now. Either way, thanks!

Comment: Aldo one would assume the field names are predetermined so it doesnr make much sense to use a `LIKE` you would probably be better off using `=`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IN ()` clause.  Because you haven't put parens around the last three `OR` conditions, the last of them, if true, will override everything else in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT point_id FROM v_ak47_test_point WHERE ak47_testsection_id= $secID
  and result_text != 'obsolete' and fieldname like 'expected_result_up' and 
  resultsfields_value = IN (140, 846, 1000)
```

Also, since you have no `%` wildcard with `fieldname like 'expected_result_up'`, don't use `LIKE` where a simple `fieldname = 'expected_result_up'` will do.  (Unless that's just placeholder data, and you actually intend to use something more complicated)

Comment: It's actually the reverse, it was something more complex that I copied and haven't cleaned up yet. The actual php call uses =